# How do I check if a Sql server string is null or empty

Tags: string, sql-server-2005, null

I want to check for data, but ignore it if it's null or empty. Currently the query is as follows...

```
Select              
Coalesce(listing.OfferText, company.OfferText, '') As Offer_Text,         
from tbl_directorylisting listing  
 Inner Join tbl_companymaster company            
  On listing.company_id= company.company_id
```

But I want to get `company.OfferTex`t if `listing.Offertext` is an empty string, as well as if it's null.

What's the best performing solution?

Answer (score 490, accepted):

I think this:

```
SELECT 
  ISNULL(NULLIF(listing.Offer_Text, ''), company.Offer_Text) AS Offer_Text
FROM ...
```

is the most elegant solution.

And to break it down a bit in pseudo code:

```
// a) NULLIF:
if (listing.Offer_Text == '')
  temp := null;
else
  temp := listing.Offer_Text; // may now be null or non-null, but not ''
// b) ISNULL:
if (temp is null)
  result := true;
else
  result := false;
```

Comment: I couldn't decide if I should upvote your answer or unclefofa's, since he seems to have answered first, but his answer has been edited after you answered.
I ended upvoting both.

Comment: if listing.Offer_Text = '    ', it passes the NULLIF condition. I am sadfused.

Comment: As long as company.Offer_Text isn't null but then this will complicate things... =)

Comment: Shouldn't we use trim to make sure everything goes as planned

Comment: @irfandar - Well, if you want to treat a string with all spaces as empty, go ahead use trim. Otherwise a string with all spaces is not empty.

Comment: This is also a good way to emmulate `IIF(ISITNULL??, yes_value, no_value)` (It is weird to use `ISNULL` as the first argument due to it wanting two arguments of its own). Instead you can do `ISNULL(NULLIF(no_value, Null), yes_value)`

Answer (score 67):

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN LEN(listing.OfferText) > 0 THEN listing.OfferText 
        ELSE COALESCE(Company.OfferText, '') END 
   AS Offer_Text,

...
```

In this example, if `listing.OfferText` is NULL, the LEN() function should also return NULL, but that's still not > 0.

**Update**

I've learned some things in the 5 1/2 years since posting this, and do it much differently now:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(listing.OfferText,''), Company.OfferText, '')
```

This is similar to the accepted answer, but it also has a fallback in case `Company.OfferText` is also null. None of the other current answers using `NULLIF()` also do this.

Comment: This got upvoted today, so it's indexed somewhere. I now know a better way to do this than the original answer.

Answer (score 36):

```
Select              
CASE
    WHEN listing.OfferText is null or listing.OfferText = '' THEN company.OfferText
    ELSE COALESCE(Company.OfferText, '')
END As Offer_Text,         
from tbl_directorylisting listing  
 Inner Join tbl_companymaster company            
  On listing.company_id= company.company_id
```

Answer (score 18):

Here is another solution:

```
SELECT Isnull(Nullif(listing.offertext, ''), company.offertext) AS offer_text, 
FROM   tbl_directorylisting listing 
       INNER JOIN tbl_companymaster company 
         ON listing.company_id = company.company_id
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use `ISNULL` and check the answer against the known output:

```
SELECT case when ISNULL(col1, '') = '' then '' else col1 END AS COL1 FROM TEST
```

Answer (score 13):

In SQL Server 2012 you have `IIF`, e.g you can use it like

```
SELECT IIF(field IS NULL, 1, 0) AS IsNull
```

The same way you can check if field is empty.

Answer (score 7):

Use the LEN function to check for null or empty values. You can just use LEN(@SomeVarcharParm) > 0. This will return false if the value is NULL, '', or ' '. This is because LEN(NULL) returns NULL and NULL > 0 returns false. Also, LEN(' ') returns 0. See for yourself run:

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN NULL > 0 THEN 'NULL > 0 = true' ELSE 'NULL > 0 = false' END,
 CASE WHEN LEN(NULL) > 0 THEN 'LEN(NULL) = true' ELSE 'LEN(NULL) = false' END,
 CASE WHEN LEN('') > 0 THEN 'LEN('''') > 0 = true' ELSE 'LEN('''') > 0 = false' END,
 CASE WHEN LEN(' ') > 0 THEN 'LEN('' '') > 0 = true' ELSE 'LEN('' '') > 0 = false' END,
 CASE WHEN LEN(' test ') > 0 THEN 'LEN('' test '') > 0 = true' ELSE 'LEN('' test '') > 0 = false' END
```

Comment: When you say "... LEN(NULL) returns NULL and NULL > 0 returns false...", the true rule is that every test or comparaison with NULL return NULL !

Comment: Right that is worth noting, but this works as a shortcut because the comparison makes the null coalesce to the correct boolean so this wouldn't work for the inverse comparison of LEN(NULL) = 0 when we want to return true for null or empty.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread but I just saw one of the earlier posts above and it is not correct.

If you are using **LEN(...)** to determine whether the field is **NULL or EMPTY** then you need to use it as follows:

```
...WHEN LEN(ISNULL(MyField, '')) < 1 THEN NewValue...
```

Answer (score 4):

this syntax :

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_directorylisting listing
WHERE (civilite_etudiant IS NULL)
```

worked for me in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3)

Answer (score 4):

```
Select              
Coalesce(NullIf(listing.OfferText, ''), NullIf(company.OfferText, ''), '') As Offer_Text,         
from tbl_directorylisting listing  
 Inner Join tbl_companymaster company            
  On listing.company_id= company.company_id
```

Comment: Plus one for the first answer (5 years later) to use both `NULLIF()` and coalesce to an empty string if `company.OfferText` is null. However, the 2nd `NULLIF()` call here serves no purpose, as if that value an empty string you're just going to coalesce back to an empty string anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This simple combination of COALESCE and NULLIF should do the trick:

```
SELECT             
  Coalesce(NULLIF(listing.OfferText, ''), company.OfferText) As Offer_Text
...
```

*Note: Add another empty string as the last COALESCE argument if you want the statement to return an empty string instead of NULL if both values are NULL.*

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution, but I don't know if it's the best....

```
Select              
Coalesce(Case When Len(listing.Offer_Text) = 0 Then Null Else listing.Offer_Text End, company.Offer_Text, '') As Offer_Text,         
from tbl_directorylisting listing  
 Inner Join tbl_companymaster company            
  On listing.company_id= company.company_id
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT              
    COALESCE(listing.OfferText, 'company.OfferText') AS Offer_Text,         
FROM 
    tbl_directorylisting listing  
    INNER JOIN tbl_companymaster company ON listing.company_id= company.company_id
```

Answer (score 3):

To check if variable is null or empty use this:

```
IF LEN(ISNULL(@var, '')) = 0
    -- Is empty or NULL
ELSE
    -- Is not empty and is not NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the records with `Empty` or `Null` value in SQL result

we can simply add       `..... WHERE Column_name != '' or 'null'`

Comment: This would be the first port of call but if you are doing things like concatenating from multiple columns in a table for example, then this would exclude the row rather than just display a blank for that column

Answer (score 2):

```
[Column_name] IS NULL OR LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM([Column_name]))) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

[Column_name] > ' '  excludes Nulls and empty strings. There is a space between the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with `VARCHAR`/`NVARCHAR` data most other examples treat white-space the same as empty string which is equal to C# function `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

This version respects white-space and works the same as the C# function `IsNullOrEmpty`:

```sql
IIF(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(val), 0) = 0, whenTrueValue, whenFalseValue)
```

Simple test:

```
SELECT
    '"' + val + '"' AS [StrValue],
    IIF(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(val), 0) = 0, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS IsNullOrEmpty
FROM ( VALUES 
    (NULL), 
    (''), 
    (' '), 
    ('a'), 
    ('a ')
) S (val)
```

Answer (score 0):

This caters for spaces as well.

```
(len(rtrim(ltrim(isnull(MyField,'')))) !=0
```