# How do check if a parameter is empty or null in Sql Server stored procedure in IF statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I read this: [How do I check if a Sql server string is null or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334108/how-do-i-check-if-a-sql-server-string-is-null-or-empty) but it not helped me in this situation.

The piece of code from my stored procedure:

```
IF (@item1 IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@item1) > 0)
        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TEST1'
    ELSE
        SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TEST2'
 PRINT @sql;
```

`@item1` is `NVARCHAR(1000)` type.

When execute this stored procedure, I provided the value for `item1`

```
EXEC    [dbo].[my_proc]
        @item1 = N''
```

it shows

`SELECT * FROM TEST1` // it is correct if `@item1 = N'some'`

instead of

`SELECT * FROM TEST2`

It is somewhere a function in sql to verify if a string is null or empty **OR** I made somewhere a mistake ?

Like in C# -> `string.IsNullOrEmpty(myValue)`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

that is the right behavior.

if you set @`item1` to a value the below expression will be true

```
IF (@item1 IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@item1) > 0)
```

Anyway in SQL Server there is not a such function but you can create your own:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsNullOrEmpty(@x varchar(max)) returns bit as
BEGIN
IF @SomeVarcharParm IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@SomeVarcharParm) > 0
    RETURN 0
ELSE
    RETURN 1
END
```

Comment: Yes, my mistake was at `OR` instead of `AND`.

Answer (score 17):

To check if variable is null or empty use this:

```
IF LEN(ISNULL(@var, '')) = 0
    -- Is empty or NULL
ELSE
    -- Is not empty and is not NULL
```

Comment: I like this idea, but would love to test the io performance against other methods.

Answer (score 4):

Of course that works; when `@item1 = N''`, it `IS NOT NULL`.

You can define `@item1` as `NULL` by default at the top of your stored procedure, and then not pass in a parameter.

Comment: Solved. The problem was `OR`. So I changed to `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check if the value is empty then transform as null 
and then check if null , then make as zero 
Finally check if equal to zero

```
IF ISNULL(NULLIF(@item1,''), 0) = 0
BEGIN
     SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TEST2'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TEST1'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following in 2012 and it worked:

```
if (@MyCode  != '' and @MyCode is not null)
BEGIN
 --statements if not null or empty
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
 --statements if null or empty
END
```