# IF Statement logic not working in TSQL --> What am I doing wrong

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, if-statement

Been a while since I been coding in T-SQL, but I have an IF statement not working in a function. It must be a logic issue on my end but I can't see it.

If a piece of data, `@pTownship` is not blank and null than I am testing it to see if it is one, two, or three characters in length and returning the township number to the calling stored procedure.  Following is my function code.

The issue is that when a piece of data, say 05N, is passed as `@pTownship`, the outer `IF` is not true the else is being executed so my internal `IF` conditions are never being executed. Since `@pTownship` is 05N it's NOT '' or NULL so why isn't my true condition being executed?

Thanks in advance for a second set of eyes.

```
CREATE FUNCTION core.fnTownshipNumber (@pTownship VARCHAR(50)) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TownshipNumber INT,
            @InputLength INT;

    IF @pTownship <> '' AND @pTownship <> NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @InputLength = LEN(@pTownship);

        -- single character, based on the data, single character is always number so return it
        IF @InputLength = 1
            SET @TownshipNumber = CONVERT(INT, @pTownship);

        -- double character, based on the data, double char are always number so return it
        IF @InputLength = 2
            SET @TownshipNumber = CONVERT(INT, @pTownship);

        -- triple character, based on the data, third char is always direction so return first two   
        IF @InputLength = 3
            SET @TownshipNumber = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@pTownship, 1, 2));
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @TownshipNumber = NULL;
    END;

    RETURN @TownshipNumber;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <> operator is not meant to compare to NULL. When you need to check for NULL, use

```
@pTownship IS NOT NULL
```

or if you prefer,

```
NOT (@pTownship IS NULL)
```

Related: [Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5658457/1132334)

In your case, you are comparing against both the empty string and null, a more concise way to capture both cases would be this:

```
IF NULLIF(@pTownship, '') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    /* ... */
END
```

You could omit the outer IF entirely, if you used this alternative:

```
SET @InputLength = LEN(COALESCE(@pTownship, ''));
```

The `COALESCE` function returns its second argument (the empty string in the example) when the first argument is NULL.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the answer and the "better" / more concise explanation as well.

Comment: fyi: From the documentation for [`Len()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**."

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to use the following form:

```
IF (@pTownship IS NOT NULL) AND (LEN(@pTownship) > 0)
```

I am not as certain about the second term; variations might also work. Parentheses could perhaps be omitted, but I might prefer to keep them.

On this, see [How do check if a parameter is empty or null in Sql Server stored procedure in IF statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264602/how-do-check-if-a-parameter-is-empty-or-null-in-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-i?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The following shows another way of implementing the logic with a [`case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) *expression* (not *statement*).

The first `case` implements the logic in a clear manner, though the initial `when` clause isn't really needed due to the `else` as a catch-all clause. The second variation takes advantage of `Left()` (or `Substring()`) tolerating a length greater than the input: it simply returns the entire string without error.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Townships as Table ( Township VarChar(16) );
insert into @Townships ( Township ) values
  ( NULL ), ( '1' ), ( '23' ), ( '45N' ), ( 'Upper Lemming' );

-- Demonstrate conversion.
select Township,
  case
    when Township is NULL or Township = '' then NULL -- This can be left to the   else   clause.
    when Len( Township ) in ( 1, 2 ) then Cast( Township as Int )
    when Len( Township ) = 3 then Cast( Left( Township, 2 ) as Int )
    else NULL end as TownshipNumber,
  case
    -- Since   Left()   doesn't mind being asked for more characters than are available ...
    when Len( Township ) between 1 and 3 then Cast( Left( Township, 2 ) as Int )
    else NULL end as TownshipNumberX
  from @Townships;
```