# how to check empty field in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have a sql query which shows address1 in a field and address2 as 'address1,address2'.My query is

```
(S.Address1 + '  ,  ' + S.Address2)as Address1
```

But when the values in the Address2 is blank it shows 
              'address1,'
 and i need to show only address1.How can i remove comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J W is close, I think, but the actual formula you want, I believe, is:

```
S.Address1 + COALESCE('  ,  ' + NULLIF(S.Address2,''),'') as Address1
```

(Below not relevant, since OP has now said the column value is blank, not `NULL`)

<strike>But you also have another issue - the above won't work (yet) because you apparently have `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` set to `OFF`. This need to be turned on (usually by setting `ANSI_NULLS` to `ON`), [since](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176056.aspx):</strike>

> In a future version of SQL Server `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` will always be `ON` and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Comment: can u tell me the exact difference between COALESCE and ISNULL?

Comment: @Anilkumar - `ISNULL` is T-SQL dialect, is limited to only two inputs, and forces the type of the result to be the same as the type of its first input, no matter what the type precedence rules would normally say. `COALESCE` is standard SQL, extends to multiple inputs (returning the first non-NULL value) and performs normal type precedence to determine the result type. Outside of a few edge cases (not present here), I'd always choose `COALESCE`.

Comment: @Anilkumar http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4274/performance-difference-for-coalesce-versus-isnull

Answer (score 5):

use `COALESCE`

```
(COALESCE(S.Address1,'') + '  ,  ' + COALESCE(S.Address2, '')) as Address1
```

- [TSQL COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

but the problem of the statement above is that it will have trailing `,` when the `address2` is null, to fix

```
(COALESCE(S.Address1,'')  + COALESCE(' , ' + S.Address2, '')) as Address1
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
CASE WHEN S.Address2 = '' 
     THEN S.Address1
     ELSE S.Address1 + '  ,  ' + S.Address2
END  AS Addrss
```

Comment: +1 for coalesce instead of isnull, since coalesce is sql standand

Comment: Need to put the comma inside the second `COALESCE`.

Comment: And due to changing requirements, now we need a `NULLIF` too. *sigh*

Comment: @Anilkumar you have mentioned in your question that those are `NULL` not blank.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(Address1                                      -- concatenation of address 1 with..
           , CASE WHEN ISNULL(NULLIF(Address2, ''))         -- if address 22 is null or empty
             THEN ''                                        -- concat with nothing
             ELSE CONCAT( '  ,  ', Address2)                -- else concat with a comma and address 2
             END
       )
```

[Sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/10074)

The line `CASE WHEN ISNULL(NULLIF(Address2, ''))` is for determine if address2 is null or empty. [Details can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334108/how-do-i-check-if-a-sql-server-string-is-null-or-empty).

Answer (score 1):

If address2 can be either null or an empty string, or simply whitespace, you need something like:

```
select address1 + 
case when length(trim(ifnull(address2, ''))) > 0 then ', ' + address2
else '' end
```