# SQL Update if parameter is not null or empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I searched some ways to check if a SQL Server parameter is not null or empty but I'm not sure what's the best way to use this when updating several columns:

I had this code at first that was updating without checking for empty or Null values:

```
UPDATE [Users] 
SET FirstName = @firstname, City = @city, Address = @address, ....
WHERE ID = @iduser
```

Then I added an `IF` clause before updating, it is working this way but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it, it is going to be long if I have to update several columns.

```
--Check if parameter is not null or empty before updating the column
IF (@firstname IS NOT NULL AND @firstname != '')
   UPDATE [Users] 
   SET FirstName = @firstname 
   WHERE ID = @iduser

IF (@city IS NOT NULL AND @city != '')
   UPDATE [Users] 
   SET City = @city 
   WHERE ID = @iduser
   ...
   ...
```

If the value is Null or Empty I don't need to update, just keep the original value in the database.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

not sure what you are trying to achieve if it is blank, but I would try using `IsNull()` I don't think there is an `IsBlank()`, but it shouldn't be too hard to write yourself

Using just `IsNull` your query would look something like...

```
Update [Users]
set    FirstName = IsNull(@FirstName, FirstName),
       City = IsNull(@City, City)
       ....
Where  ...
```

this will Update the row with the param value if they are NOT null, otherwise update it to itself aka change nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, you guide me to the correct answer.  I ended up using: ISNULL(NULLIF(@City, ''), City):                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334108/how-do-i-check-if-a-sql-server-string-is-null-or-empty   I'm not sure if I should close this

Comment: @Alex `NULLIF` using for ***VARCHAR columns***, not for another _datatypes_

Comment: Can we alse use Coalesce() for this?

Comment: I am using `COALESCE` with postgresql and it works!

Simply do this:
`UPDATE table SET column =COALESCE(newValue, column) WHERE condition = true`

Comment: How is this correct?  COALESCE and ISNULL do _not_ handle empty strings like nulls: https://i.imgur.com/6nNMy7G.png

Comment: for googlers: If you are using PL SQL, could use `City = NVL(:City, City)` instead. See: [NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/NVL.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
Update [Users]
set    FirstName = iif(ISNULL(ltrim(rtrim(@FirstName)), '')='', FirstName, @FirstName),
       ....
Where  ...
```