# Why can't SQL Server return null values?

Tags: sql-server-2016

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[drugTP] 
WHERE [DrugRate] IS NULL
```

[image]

When I run this query, SQL Server returns an empty grid, why?

Comment: are your values null or empty strings?

Comment: A value of NULL indicates that the value is unknown. A value of NULL is different from an empty or zero value. No two null values are equal. Comparisons between two null values, or between a NULL and any other value, return unknown because the value of each NULL is unknown

Comment: I think values are empty. so how can i handle it

Comment: You Need to Read [How to Ask a Query on Stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a Sql server string is null or empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334108/how-do-i-check-if-a-sql-server-string-is-null-or-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the value in the column is not a "NULL" value but an empty string.

You can try matching the empty string

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[drugTP] 
WHERE [DrugRate] IS NULL or [DrugRate] = ''
```

or using the function NULLIF, that returns NULL if the two parameters are equal

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[drugTP] 
WHERE NULLIF([DrugRate],'') IS NULL
```