# SQL Query To Return Phone Number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server hat has:

```
FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, CellNumber, HomeNumber
John Smith M 111-111-1111, 222-222-2222
```

The person can have both CellNumber and HomeNumber or can have CellNumber but no HomeNumber or can have HomeNumber and no CellNumber.

How do i write a query that will always return CellNumber if exists and HomeNumber only if CellNumber is NULL or blank.

SQL query to produce following results:

```
FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, NumberToUse, PhoneType
John Smith M 111-111-1111 CellNumber
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a Sql server string is null or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334108/how-do-i-check-if-a-sql-server-string-is-null-or-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is `Coalesce()` in concert with `NullIf()`

**Example**

```
Select FirstName 
      ,LastName
      ,MiddleName 
      ,DefaultPhone = coalesce(NullIf(CellNumber,'')+' Cell',NullIf(HomeNumber,'')+' Home')
 from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `case`:

```
select . . .,
       (case when cellNumber is not null or cellNumber <> '' then cellNumber else homeNumber en) as NumberToUse,
       (case when cellNumber is not null  or cellNumber <> '' then 'Cell' else 'Home' end) as PhoneType
from t;
```

If blank could include spaces, you can remove the spaces (for the comparison) using `replace()` or `ltrim()`.

The comparison to for `is not null` is, strictly speaking, not necessary.  But it makes the query's intention more obvious.

Comment: That will return blank cellNumbers.  Also if cellNumber is not null or cellNumber = '' will return 'Cell'?  C'mon Gordon.  Oh man, I corrected Gordon Linoff.  :)

Comment: That's better.  :)

Comment: @GordonBell . . . When I first read the query, I missed the part about blanks.  I didn't do a very good job on the edit the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Just one case when statement to first check if CellNumber is available, else fallback to HomeNumber.

```
SELECT 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    MiddleName,
    CASE WHEN  
        CellNumber IS NOT NULL THEN CellNumber
    ELSE 
        HomeNumber 
    END AS NumberToUse,
    PhoneType
FROM
    TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

coalesce is your friend here.. it returns the first non null values in the list.. so you don't have to do a whole heap of case statements

```
 select coalesce(cellnumber,HomeNumber) from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select FirstName, LastName, MiddleName,
case when isnull(CellNumber, '') = '' then HomeNumber else CellNumber end as NumberToUse,
case when isnull(CellNumber, '') = '' then 'HomeNumber' else 'CellNumber' end as PhoneType
from ...
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.